# How to disable some of the options in a select?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, select

I have a `<select>` list. In it, the user does not have access to some of the options (user can see those options but can not select them).

Is there any helper available in Ruby on Rails to do this?

Comment: please provide a complete detail and what have you done in order to achieve this ?/

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you will probably use the `select` helper.

Reference: [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

In this case, this:

```ruby
select("post", "category", Post::CATEGORIES, {:disabled => 'restricted'})
```

could become:

```html
<select name="post[category]">
  <option></option>
  <option>joke</option>
  <option>poem</option>
  <option disabled="disabled">restricted</option>
</select>
```

Instead of supplying an array of disabled options, using the `collection_select` method, you can also supply a Proc:

```ruby
collection_select(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, \
                  {:disabled => lambda{|category| category.archived? }})
```

If the categories “2008 stuff” and “Christmas” return true when the method archived? is called, this would return:

```html
<select name="post[category_id]">
  <option value="1" disabled="disabled">2008 stuff</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Christmas</option>
  <option value="3">Jokes</option>
  <option value="4">Poems</option>
</select>
```

---

You can also supply an array of disabled options in the options hash to the `options_for_select` method. Reference: [apidock.com](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

**Example with an array of disabled options**

```ruby
options_for_select(["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"], \
                   :disabled => ["Advanced", "Super Platinum"])
```

Gives:

```html
<option value="Free">Free</option>
<option value="Basic">Basic</option>
<option value="Advanced" disabled="disabled">Advanced</option>
<option value="Super Platinum" disabled="disabled">Super Platinum</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.select :action_item_status, action_item_status, {}, {:disabled => true} %>
```

Comment: This will disable a whole select list

Answer (score 0):

manually construct options and set disabled attributes 
 `<option disabled="disabled"></option>` and try disabled option